# Oracle SQL - Regular Expression matching using REGEXP_REPLACE()

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-replace

Good morning,

I am hoping to find assistance with writing a select query to remove some text from a column.

I have created a column called "TEXT_MINING" in a previous query, that some code a different developer wrote will perform some text mining analysis on. The TEXT_MINING column has text that looks like:

EMPLOYEE FOUND BROKEN HANDLE ON HAMMER * 02-08-18 15:19:22 PM * I found a hammer that had the wood split on the handle, tossed into scrap.

I want to remove the * and all of the text in between the two * to help my software engineer do some text mining. Here is my current dilemma:

Not only do I not know how to use REGEXP_REPLACE, but I can't get the REGEXP worked out. I currently have:

```
^[*]\w[*]$
```

So it looks like:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '^[*]\w[*]$', '')
```

Could anyone advise?

Thank you!

Comment: I fail to see why "text mining" cannot handle the original column, but that is an entirely different matter.

Comment: @GordonLinoff You are exactly correct there...but I am just trying to do as I am told

Comment: Can the string have multiple `*`s?

Comment: Never, at least not that I have EVER seen @GordonLinoff. However, I think the solutions below worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this approach to remove 1+ occurrences of `*...*` substrings in your column:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
   'EMPLOYEE FOUND BROKEN HANDLE ON HAMMER * 02-08-18 15:19:22 PM * I found a hammer that had the wood split on the handle, tossed into scrap.', 
   '\s*\*[^*]*\*', 
   ''
) as Result from dual
```

See the [online demo](http://rextester.com/LFJH65487)

**Pattern details**

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\*` - a `*` char
- `[^*]*` - 0+ chars other than `*`
- `\*` - a `*` char.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cePYHh/1).

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this and for your explanation! This is great!

Comment: This is a safer solution because it stops at the next `*` rather than the last one.

Comment: Wiktor, this is fantastic and I am going to move forward from this. I also appreciate you taking the time to break out the "pattern details" for me. I learn a lot on this and am appreciative of your time.

Comment: @bm0r3son Note that `*` is a special char (an operator, called a quantifier) denoting *0 or more occurrences of the pattern it modifies*), thus you need to escape it to match as a literal `*` char (like `"\*"`), *but* if it is inside a character set, bracket expression, you do not have to escape it (`"[*]"`).

Answer (score 2):

This could be a way:

```
select regexp_replace(yourString, '\*.*\*', '') from yourTable
```

Please notice that this will remove everything between the first and the last '*' in the string; for example:

```
with test(x) as (
select 'Something * something else * and a * just before another * and something more' from dual
)
select regexp_replace(x, '\*.*\*', '') from test
```

gives:

```
Something  and something more
```

Comment: I employed this method and it worked perfectly. It is simple and effective. Would it be better to use Wiktor's regular expression above? This method worked amazing for me. Thank you!

Comment: @bm0r3son This `\*.*\*` will make `Hi ` out of `Hi *Tom*, have you met *Jim?*` because `.*` matches up to the last `*` occurrence.

Comment: @bm0r3son: the two expressions do different things, it only depends on what best suits your need

Comment: Thank you so much!